# passing data to post action through ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with the post action , receives empty object 
I have this javascript code to call that action

```js
 function forwardMsg(result) {
        
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("ForwardHCFASuspendedMessage")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:JSON.stringify( {
                     messageId: "@Model.MessageId",
                    result: result,
                    serviceLines: "@Model.ServiceLineSegment"
                }),

                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }

            });
        }
```

, and receive an empty object as shown in this image 
[image]

Comment: If you don't have proper routing with first element name data, try to parameter name 'id' instead 'data' in your function, like this: 
`public ActionResult ForwardHCFASuspendedMessage(ForwardMessageModel id)`

Comment: If you send a model in javascript, you must receive a model variable as a parameter in your controller; if you send id, serviceLines, whatever, you must receive the proper data type

Comment: Did you try pass it in other way, something like that:
`var varl = JSON.stringify( {
                     messageId: "@Model.MessageId",
                    result: result,
                    serviceLines: "@Model.ServiceLineSegment"
                });`
and your url line in ajax request:
`url: '@Url.Action("ForwardHCFASuspendedMessage", "YourControllerName")' + '/' + val`

Comment: Don't use `JSON.stringify()` - its just `data { messageId: "@Model.MessageId", ...}, (either that or specify the `contentType: 'json',` option. But you will never get `serviceLines` because its a collection property and `@Model.ServiceLineSegment` will only return its `.ToString()` value (although what is the point of degrading your app by sending it to the client and then sending it back again unchanged?)

Comment: @Marcin thanks for advice, but like this it would be sent on the url , this can't be with an object with large amount of data.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes you're right but i did all this stuff to get that list of servicelines. Anyway i have sringfied the data i wanted and this humble solution just worked

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's [`$post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
var data = {
    messageId: "@Model.MessageId",
    result: result,
    serviceLines: "@Model.ServiceLineSegment"
};

$.post('@Url.Action("ForwardHCFASuspendedMessage")', JSON.stringify(data))
.success(function (response) {
    alert(response);
})
.fail(function (response) {
    alert(response.responseText);
});
```

This can take care of setting up and ajax call for posting JSON data to an endpoint. That means all the hard work is done for you, áll you need to supply is the url and data.

EDIT:

Try the call without `serviceLines: "@Model.ServiceLineSegment"` and see what happens. You need to convert that into a JavaScript array, before making the POST call, since seeing:

`System.Collections.Generic .List`1[XIP.Infrastructure.Data.Claims.ServiceLineSegment_HCFA]"`

in the request body is not what you want. I think you can do this:

```
var data = {
    messageId: "@Model.MessageId",
    result: result,
    serviceLines: JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Model.ServiceLineSegment)')
};
```

Comment: I see the sent data after response from the browser net, I see it's already sent like this "{"messageId":"e2911271-c0a1-4f5e-9773-39e669c576d8","result":1,"serviceLines":"System.Collections.Generic
.List`1[XIP.Infrastructure.Data.Claims.ServiceLineSegment_HCFA]"}" but dont know why it wasnt been received in the action

Comment: is it a problem with in the routing config ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function forwardMsg(result) {
var obj = {messageId: "@Model.MessageId",
                    result: result,
                    serviceLines: "@Model.ServiceLineSegment"};
        var jsonStringHere = JSON.stringify(obj);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url?action=ForwardHCFASuspendedMessage',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {jsonStringReceiver:jsonStringHere},
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }

            });
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

[image]

My code at cshtml:

```
$(function () {
    function forwardMsg() {
        var dataToSend = JSON.stringify({
            Id: @Model.Id,
            SomeData: '@Model.SomeData',
            Result: "Another test data"
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("ForwardHCFASuspendedMessage", "Home")',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: dataToSend,

            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }

        });
    }

    $('body').on('click', '#myBtn', forwardMsg);
});
```

It start to works for me after adding:

```
contentType: 'application/json',
```